# Problem involving a modulus function, problem finding the intersecting points.

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, functions

$Y = |1/2X|$ and $Y = 3 + 2X$

I have to find the intersecting points by algebra only,

What I performed,
$|1/2X| = 3 + 2X$

$1/2X  = (3 + 2X) or -(3 + 2X) $

The $2$ possible values of $x$ are $-2$ or $-6/5$ leading the only intersecting point $(-6/5, 3/5)$

This contradicts both a rough graph I drew and the answers in my manual which specifically are $(-2, -1)$ & $(-6/5, -3/5)$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $y=\left| \frac12 x\right| \geq 0$, the manual is wrong.

Your solution seems to be correct.